# Fill Input Field with selected option with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm still learn how to use JQuery and using codeigniter as it's framework, so maybe this is simple but it's hard for me, i have the logic but i don't know how to implement it.

But, basically what i want to do is, from the image below u can see 2 box, i want when the red box selected the query result **fill** the lightblue box with certain data

[image]

the data come from 1 table and the table name is `progdi_list` here is the table structure, progdi=`kodePS` and strata=`strata`. When the `select input`of `progdi` selected the query read the whole `row` right?

so i need to get only the `strata` value and put it in the lightblue box, how to do that? how to make the query and also parse the data between MVC paradigm

[image]

Comment: In your js file just add on change event on red box and then use the jquery AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

Comment: Show some code and we can help

Comment: Anda orang Indonesia? Apakah anda sudah menginclude kan plugin jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this you can use jquery on change function, check the example:

```
$("progadi").on("change", function() {

var val = $(this).val();
// put the val in other field

$("strata").val(val);
});
```